# LINQ to SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I know this is a duplicate on SO, but I can't figure out how to use the contains operator in my specific code:

I have 5 bookings in the database:

ID, Booking, Pren, ReservationCode

1, VisitHere, 1, 1000A

2, VisitHere, 1, 1000A

3, VisitHere, 1, 1000A

4, VisitThere, 2, 2000A

5, VisitThere, 2, 2000A

```
    public int SpecialDelete(DataContext db, IEnumerable<BookingType> bookings) {

        var rescodes = (from b in bookings
                        select b).Distinct().ToArray();
        // Code Breaks here
        IEnumerable<BookingType> bookingsToDelete = db.GetTable<BookingType>().Where(b => bookings.Any(p => p.Pren == b.Pren && p.ReservationCode == b.ReservationCode));

        int deleted = bookingsToDelete.Count();
        db.GetTable<BookingType>().DeleteAllOnSubmit(bookingsToDelete);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return deleted;
    }
```

When I pass the first record into this method (1, VisitHere, 1, 1000A), I want it to retrieve ids 1,2 and 3, but not 4 and 5.

I can do this by matching Pren and ReservationCode.

How can I do this as the .Any and .All operators are throwing the above exception?

**Note:** The method must accept a list of bookings because the argument will always be multiple bookings passed into the method, I just used a single booking as an example.

**Edit:** I basically need LINQ2SQL to generate a bunch of SQL statements like so (let's say I want to delete all records in my DB):

```
DELETE
FROM Bookings b
WHERE b.ReservationCode = '1000A' AND b.Pren = 1

DELETE
FROM Bookings b
WHERE b.ReservationCode = '2000A' AND b.Pren = 2
```

Comment: Can you use the `ID` values of the `bookings`?

Comment: @GertArnold (even though I've marked the answer) No I can't use IDs I only get a header record (my DB is far more complex than I have written here) - So I get ID 1 and must delete 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is trying to direct you to use the .Contains method passing in a simple array. By default it translates that array into an `In` clause in the format:

`Where foo In ("b1", "B2", "B3")`

Notice here that you can't do a multi-dimentional array in the In clause (as you would need to do). Since you can't join server side to a local array, your options become limited as long as you have a composite key relationship.

If you don't need to fetch the rows in order to delete them, it will probably be faster anyway to just use Context's ExecuteCommand to issue your deletes. Just make sure to parameterize your query (see http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Does-LINQ-to-SQL-eliminate-the-possibility-of-SQL-Injection)

```
string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Bookings b WHERE b.ReservationCode = {0} AND b.Pren = {1}";
foreach (var bookingType in bookings)
{
    db.ExecuteCommand(deleteQuery, bookingType.ReservationCode, bookingType.Preen);
}
```

Comment: This is what I have done only I potentially have 3000 records, I build the query inside the loop and then execute afterwards :)

Comment: You may want to chunk that down into batches of 100 records or so each. Assuming you are parameterizing the queries, SQL Server won't let you pass in 6000 parameters on a single query. Using string concatenation on the other hand opens you up to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks again Jim, I sanitize my data upon input, which also comes from a trustworthy source so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have a quasi temp table on the server.  You can put the list values in there.

This is a real problem with ORMs.  You have a lot is mismatch between local and remote capabilities.

I have tried even using .Range to generated a remote list to join against, but it doesn't work either.

Essentially you have to rearrange your data islands somehow ( i.e. where does the lists of pren and rs come from? Is it on the server somewhere ? ) or upload one of your local collections to a staging area on the server.

Comment: Your answer raises an interesting point, I've updated my answer with what I suppose I want L2S to do. For now I will just build and execute my own custom built SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "except the contains operator." Have you considered using the Contains operator? It should do the same thing.

So from

```
IEnumerable<BookingType> bookingsToDelete = db.GetTable<BookingType>().Where(b => bookings.Any(p => p.Pren == b.Pren && p.ReservationCode == b.ReservationCode));
```

to

```
IEnumerable<BookingType> bookingsToDelete = db.GetTable<BookingType>().Where(b => bookings.Contains(p => p.Pren == b.Pren && p.ReservationCode == b.ReservationCode));
```

I realise that the list wont contain the same objects so you may need to do something like:

```
bookings.Select(booking => booking.PrimaryKeyOfAwesome).Contains(b => b.PrimaryKeyOfAwesome) etc etc.
```

**Edited for clarity**

**Edit for humility**
Ok, so after actually recreating the entire setup I realised that my solution doesnt work because of the two parameter, not just one. Apologies. This is what I came up with in the end, which works, but is genuinely a terrible solution and should not be used. I include it here only for closure ;)

```
        public static int SpecialDelete(DataContext db, IEnumerable<BookingType> bookings)
        {
            var compositeKeys = bookings.Select(b => b.Pren.ToString() + b.ReservationCode).Distinct();
            IEnumerable<BookingType> bookingsToDelete = db.GetTable<BookingType>().Where(b => compositeKeys.Contains(b.Pren.ToString() + b.ReservationCode));

            int deleted = bookingsToDelete.Count();
            db.GetTable<BookingType>().DeleteAllOnSubmit(bookingsToDelete);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            return deleted;
        }
```

Comment: I have tried using the contains operator but it doesn't accept a predicate => query in the same way that the Any and All operators do. and your code doesn't compile :(

Comment: Contains is translated to In (1,2,3,4) for LINQ to Sql. the TSQL construct for In doesn't support multiple parameters, thus you can't evaluate the complex lambda in contains this way.